# Directly Using a Smart Charger with An Old Vector Hunting Spotlight?

Tags: batteries, 12v, light

I have an old hunting spotlight (http://documents.dewalt.com/documents/English/Instruction%20Manual/Vector/VEC184POB.pdf) which has a small 12V sealed lead-acid battery.

The chargers that come with it aren't smart chargers (And may overcharge the battery/not trickle charge it), but I have a modern smart charger and would like to use it with it.

The battery terminals aren't exposed though. The charger uses a typical 12V cigarette lighter which I can wire my smart charger to.

Can I just use the smart charger, or is it likely that this will damage the internal circuitry?

Judging by the wording of the manual, I would assume that the 12V DC source just directly charges the battery.

Comment: Question about the use of consumer products are not on topic here, in larger part because the necessary documentation to approach them in an engineering manner cannot be provided by the askers because it is not made available by the manufacturers.  You would, essentially, have to reverse engineer the product before you could ask an answerable question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh, my apologies, I didn't know. I was just asking based on a "Is my thinking about this correct" based on my reading of the manual, not a rigirous analysis of the circuitry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that all looks reasonable. You can do a continuity check with a DMM to confirm and you should be fine just charging it through the DC connector with a modern smart charger. I've seen that style of connector for sale for use with motorcycles and other 12V lead acid systems.